# Javascript: How to pass global variables/constant variable across different .js file

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an index.html written like this:

```
// index.html:

<body>
   <script>
      const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
      const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
   </script>
   <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

And I would like to modify the variables inside the .js file (the code below is my attempt, it doesn't work), but not in the index.html file, is it possible?

```
// index.js: (this is my attempt, but failed)

import "../index.html";
GAME_WIDTH -= 100;
GAME_HEIGHT -= 100;
```

(there are two files, index.html and index.js, where index.js is put in a folder called "src")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define directly on window object like

```
window.GAME_WIDTH = 800;
window.GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
```

and use this in index.js directly like `window.GAME_WIDTH -= 100;` no need to import anything if you are setting these global level.

Comment: It pops out "ReferenceError: window is not defined" in VSCode. What package should I install?

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong here: Your import statement and reassigning to a constant.

You will not even encounter the second one since an error from inside your .js file, the `import` line, will block the rest of the script in that file to execute. You do not import an html file like that. Evenmore, to have access to inline scripts of an html file inside another .js files you do not have to import the html file at all, since they will be already global you will have access to them, even you do not attach them to `window` like `window.y = 1`, `window.f = (x) => x * x`, unless they are inside a block or function block.

So:

First, delete that import line in .js file to get rid of importing error.

Then, make your *constants* inside your inline script, the one in the html file `script` tags, *variables*, since *constants*, `const`s, are constants and cannot be re-assigned. You can do this by putting `var` or `let` in their definition instead of `const`. Or you may choose not to put any of those at all in their definition unless they are inside a *block* (for `let`) or *function* (for putting `var` or `let`). The part with concern about *block* and *function* when you choose to define them with `let` or `var` is about *scope* in JavaScript language and out of scope of this post.

```js
console.log('before :', GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
GAME_WIDTH -= 100;
GAME_HEIGHT -= 100;
console.log('after: ', GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    GAME_WIDTH = 800; // Or define with var or let unless inside a block to reach it in other script files
    GAME_HEIGHT = 600; // Or define with var or let unless inside a block to reach it in other script files
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  <p>app</p>
</body>

</html>
```